# Unable to install agent in remote server(VM) for azure release pipelines(continuous deployments)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

When I tried to download and install agent(or create deployment group) in remote server, i'm getting this error-

Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." At line:1 char:1303 + ...nalString, $True);}; $WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $agentZip);Add-Type ... +~~~~~~~~~~.......

I don't know the exact reason for this error.  I thought it was because I don't have internet access for my remote server. Are there any other causes for this error?

Comment: Can you share your detailed steps when you install agent?

Comment: I created a new deployment group in azure devops, there I copied the registration script and tried to run in the remote machine(VM).

Comment: I logged into my remote machine and run the script in the PowerShell directly. It worked well on my side. Did you run the script in the same way? Can you please share the complete logs in your PowerShell?

Comment: Yes. I run the script in powershell directly by logging into my remote server. This is the exact error it's showing-

Comment: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." At line:1 char:1303 + ...nalString, $True);}; $WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $agentZip);Add-Type ... +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~ + +categoryInfo : Not specified:(:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId: WebException

Comment: @Mansa, did you figure this out? On two servers, I was able to get this to work adding in the host url to the trusted sites and making sure I'm in the Administrators group. Two other servers, same thing, but, I keep getting the error.

Comment: Hello @fafafooey, Actually no! I don't have admin access to my servers and even no internet access. I'm trying to get any one of them. I hope it works, if I have internet access in my servers. If u have internet access in your servers, just try to download and install the agent "manually". This might work for you!

Comment: @Mansa, thanks for the update. After running out of ideas, I asked the server admins if there were any group policies preventing me from downloading the file. Come to find out that there is, and it is spottily implemented, where some servers have it and others do not. After thinking about hurling myself and my machine out the .25 story window, I realized I'll have to try the manual setup. 
Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue if my remote server (VM) is not connected to the network. Please check the network of your remote machine.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. For installing agent in server, we require internet access, so, Is "https://dev.azure.com/ domain access enough for downloading and installing the agent in server??

Comment: I also saw the following error message:unable to access: vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net . I think you should add this too.

Comment: Are you sure?? If I type "vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net" in browser it's showing that this url doesn't exists. Agent Zip file is downloaded only when we enter the entire url along with azure agent version and zip file or else that url is not a valid url!! Please tell me with confirmation as I need to solve this problem as soon as possible!